# How to solve 5 pegs Tower of Hanoi?

Tags: c++

There's a problem on the 9th step. It makes wrong move

I was looking for a solution. I didn't find it so i tried to change Hanoi 4 pegs code to 5 pegs. And it doesn't work properly

```cpp
void Shift(int s, int d){
    cout<<s<<" "<<d<<endl;
}

void Hanoi5(int n, int from_rod, int to_rod,int aux_rod1, int aux_rod2, int aux_rod3)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return;
    if (n == 1) {
        Shift(from_rod,to_rod);
        return;
    }

    Hanoi5(n - 2, from_rod, aux_rod1, aux_rod2, aux_rod3, to_rod);
    Shift(from_rod, aux_rod3);
    Shift(from_rod, aux_rod2);
    Shift(from_rod, to_rod);
    Shift(aux_rod2, to_rod);
    Shift(aux_rod3, to_rod);
    Hanoi5(n - 2, aux_rod1, to_rod, from_rod, aux_rod2, aux_rod3);
}

int main(){
Hanoi5(5,1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
}
```

4 pegs solution:

```cpp
if (n == 0)
        return;
    if (n == 1) {
        Shift(from_rod,to_rod);
        return;
    }

    Hanoi4(n - 2, from_rod, aux_rod1, aux_rod2, to_rod);
    Shift(from_rod, aux_rod2);
    Shift(from_rod, to_rod);
    Shift(aux_rod2, to_rod);
    Hanoi4(n - 2, aux_rod1, to_rod, from_rod,aux_rod2);
```

I need a list of moves and on 9th something goes wrong

Comment: What algorithm are you trying to implement? [The one from Wikipedia?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#With_four_pegs_and_beyond) Do you have a pen and paper solution you can try and replicate in code? Do you have more restrictions, e.g. [adjacent pegs only](https://github.com/ErkanSensei/5-Hanoi-Pegs)? There must be plenty of literature on this.

Answer (score 5):

Your algorithm is similar to the standard 3-peg algorithm, except you're moving three disks at a time instead of one by using the extra pegs.

Since you're moving 3 disks at a time, you need to decrease `n` by 3 in the recursive calls instead of 2. You also need special handling for the `n==2` case.

Note that your algorithm will not give the minimum possible number of moves. The optimal algorithm (optimality only proven in 2018) is the [Frame-Stewart algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#Frame%E2%80%93Stewart_algorithm).